# Push failed: Unable to access URL : The requested URL returned error: 409

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have successfully checkout in my android studio from git repository but when I try to push then prompt me this error

Push failed: Unable to access 'repository url': The requested URL returned error: 409

And not asking me about credential as well.

Comment: navigate to ur git repo .. and its not repository url .. its just the `branchName` in which u wanna push .. `git push origin your_Branch_name`

Answer (score 0):

Since your studio is not prompting dialog to enter git username and password, so you need to do following things:

**Step 1**: Goto settings **>** Appearance and Behaviour **>** System settings **>** passwords **>** check button of "Do not save password, forgot password after restart".

**Step 2**: Click File **>** Invalidate Caches/ Restart and go for Invalidate and restart.

After opening the Android studio again:

Try to push the code from terminal again by following commands:

But before that right click on App package **>** show in explorer and delete **.git** folder at Topmost. and open **.idea** and delete VCS file.

Follow these commands-

**1.** Git init

**2.** Git add remote origin

**3.** Git add .

**4.** Git commit -m "your comment"

**5.** Git push origin *your_branch_name*

Comment: when I try to push "git push origin master" then prompt me error
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.